# Remove NA from list of lists

Tags: r, tapply

I have a matrix, data.mat, that looks like:

```
A B C D E  
45 43 45 65 23   
12 45 56 NA NA   
13 4  34 12 NA
```

I am trying to turn this into a list of lists, where each row is one list within a bigger list.  I do the following:

```
list <- tapply(data.mat,rep(1:nrow(data.mat),ncol(data.mat)),function(i)i)
```

which gives me a list of lists, with NAs included, such as:

```
$`1`  
 [1]  45 43 45 65 23  
$`2`  
 [1]  12 45 56 NA NA  
$`3`  
 [1]  13 4 34 12 NA
```

But what I want is:

```
$`1`  
 [1]  45 43 45 65 23  
$`2`  
 [1]  12 45 56   
$`3`  
 [1]  13 4 34 12
```

Is there a good way to remove the NAs either during the tapply call or after the fact?

Comment: Don't use variable names like `list` as it's used in R for lists.

Comment: Good point.  I wouldn't normally--I was just trying to make it generic for the example.  But that is good to remember, since I'm sloppy about naming conventions sometimes.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Sure, you can use `lapply` like this:

```
> lapply(list, function(x) x[!is.na(x)])
$`1`
[1] 45 43 45 65 23

$`2`
[1] 12 45 56

$`3`
[1] 13  4 34 12
```

Comment: How could I instead replace all NAs with 0 vs removing them?

Comment: ```lapply(list, function(x) { x[is.na(x)] <- 0; return(x) })``` (not tested)

Answer (score 9):

Your sample data:

```
data.mat <- data.matrix(read.table(text = "A B C D E  
45 43 45 65 23   
12 45 56 NA NA   
13 4  34 12 NA ", header = TRUE))
```

To split by row:

```
row.list <- split(data.mat, row(data.mat))
```

To remove NAs:

```
Map(Filter, list(Negate(is.na)), row.list)
```

or

```
lapply(row.list, Filter, f = Negate(is.na))
```

Everything in one shot:

```
Map(Filter, list(Negate(is.na)), split(data.mat, row(data.mat)))
```

Comment: The benefit of this method is it outputs the same `list` format even if there are no `NA`s in the data.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this:

```
apply(data.mat, 1, function(x) x[!is.na(x)])
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
 A  B  C  D  E 
45 43 45 65 23 

[[2]]
 A  B  C 
12 45 56 

[[3]]
 A  B  C  D 
13  4 34 12
```

If you don't want names:

```
apply(data.mat, 1, function(x) unname(x[!is.na(x)]))
```

If there is the possibility that every row has the same number of NAs, it will be safer to use:

```
split(apply(data.mat, 1, function(x) unname(x[!is.na(x)])), 1:nrow(data.mat))
```

Comment: Just beat me to it :)

Comment: `lapply(split(data.mat, 1:nrow(data.mat)), function(x) unname(x[!is.na(x)]))` is a bit more identical to the "desired" output, but both contain the same info.

Comment: @MrFlick True.  I feel no shame in taking the `unname` part to match that aspect better, but you may want to post yours as a separate answer.  Or I could add it to mine if you aren't inclined.  I have no shame. ;)

Comment: Personally, i think your specific shape is probably more useful and representative of the real data. I'm fine leaving it as a comment.

Comment: A problem with this approach is that it won't consistently return a list. If the number of NA was the same on each row...

Comment: @flodel Thanks for point this out.  I added a fix for that case.

Comment: without the `x` before `[!is.na(x)]` I got an error (unexpected `[`...). Should this in fact be there, so you have `x[!is.na(x)]` ? (I also see you deleted it in one of your edits).

Comment: @tospig Yes, you need the `x` in front there.  I'm not entirely sure what happened with the edits.  I must have made a mistake.