# Replace NAs in multiple list elements in R

Tags: r, list, replace, na

Assume I have the following list:

```
list(c(1:5,NA,NA),NA,c(NA,6:10))

[[1]]
[1]  1  2  3  4  5 NA NA

[[2]]
[1] NA

[[3]]
[1] NA  6  7  8  9 10
```

I want to replace all `NA`s with `0`:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 0 0

[[2]]
[1] 0

[[3]]
[1]  0  6  7  8  9 10
```

I was originally thinking `is.na` would be involved, but couldn't get it to affect all list elements. I learned from the related question ([Remove NA from list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25777104/4581200)), that using `lapply` would allow me to apply `is.na` to each element, but that post  demonstrates how to remove (not *replace*) `NA` values.

**How do I *replace* `NA` values from *multiple* list elements?**

I've tried `for` loops and `ifelse` approaches, but everything I've tried is either slow, doesn't work or just plain clunky. There's got to be a simple way to do this with an `apply` function...

Comment: `lapply(L1, function (x) ifelse(is.na(x), 0, x))`

Comment: Btw, you might want to just store them in a single table, like `data.table::rbindlist(lapply(L, function(x) data.frame(x)), id=TRUE)` in which case normal methods will work..

Comment: @janos thanks for the comment. See my [post below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49329557/4581200) for performance comparison of `lapply` approaches. `replace()` is faster than `ifelse()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And there *is*!

Here's a simple `lapply` approach using the `replace` function:

```
L1 <-list(c(1:5,NA,NA),NA,c(NA,6:10))

lapply(L1, function(x) replace(x,is.na(x),0))
```

With the desired result:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 0 0

[[2]]
[1] 0

[[3]]
[1]  0  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: Or maybe `rapply` if the list is fancier: `rapply(L, function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), 0), classes = c("logical", "integer"), how="replace")`

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to do this:

using `map` from purrrr package.

```
lt <- list(c(1:5,NA,NA),NA,c(NA,6:10))
lt %>% 
    map(~replace(., is.na(.), 0))


#output

[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 0 0

[[2]]
[1] 0

[[3]]
[1]  0  6  7  8  9 10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
kk<- list(c(1:5,NA,NA),NA,c(1,6:10))

lapply(kk, function(i) 
  { p<- which(is.na(i)==TRUE)
    i[p] <- 0
    i
  })
```

Edited upon  Gregor's commment

```
lapply(kk, function(i) {i[is.na(i)] <- 0; i})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This resembles my own early attempts. I was trying to find something a little bit easier to read/follow.

Comment: You don't need `== TRUE` ever. And in this case the `which` is redundant. Just `i[is.na(i)] <- 0; i` is fine in the body of `function(i)`.

Answer (score 1):

I've decided to **benchmark the various `lapply` approaches mentioned**:

```
lapply(Lt, function(x) replace(x,is.na(x),0)) 
lapply(Lt, function(x) {x[is.na(x)] <- 0; x})
lapply(Lt, function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), 0, x))
```

Benchmarking code:

```
Lt <- lapply(1:10000, function(x)  sample(c(1:10000,rep(NA,1000))) )    ##Sample list

elapsed.time <- data.frame(
    m1 = mean(replicate(25,system.time(lapply(Lt, function(x) replace(x,is.na(x),0)))[3])),
    m2 = mean(replicate(25,system.time(lapply(Lt, function(x) {x[is.na(x)] <- 0; x}))[3])),
    m3 = mean(replicate(25,system.time(lapply(Lt, function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), 0, x)))[3]))
  )
```

Results:

```
Function                                          Average Elapsed Time
lapply(Lt, function(x) replace(x,is.na(x),0))     0.8684 
lapply(Lt, function(x) {x[is.na(x)] <- 0; x})     0.8936
lapply(Lt, function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), 0, x))    8.3176
```

**The `replace` approach is fastest followed closely by the `[]` approach. The `ifelse` approach is 10x slower.**

Answer (score 0):

This will deal with any list depth and structure:

```
x <-  eval(parse(text=gsub("NA","0",capture.output(dput(a)))))
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 0 0
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 0
# 
# [[3]]
# [1]  0  6  7  8  9 10
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
lapply(enlist, function(x) { x[!is.na(x)]})
```

where:

```
enlist <- list(c(1:5,NA,NA),NA,c(NA,6:10))
```

This yields:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

[[2]]
logical(0)

[[3]]
[1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: Hi. I want to replace the NAs not get rid of them. Thanks.